# Problem logging into my desktop account on Xubuntu 14.04LTS

Tags: xubuntu, .desktop

My main account on Xubuntu 14.04LTS 64bit loops back to the login screen after it tries to load. guest account works, and I managed to make a new account using terminal, but I need access to all the stuff my main account has still.

What i've tried already:
-deleting/renaming/moving .XAuthority
-different display managers
-different desktop environments (MATE,E17 etc...)
-scanned disk for errors

I really need to fix this, it's a brand new computer that i've really been happy with and had no problems until this.

Comment: Perhaps this will help http://askubuntu.com/questions/463846/cant-login-to-my-account-i-know-the-password